# Javascript/Jquery code crashing my browser

Tags: javascript

Sort of new to working with web stuff, so sorry if this is a stupid question, however, I can't seem to comprehend why the javascript code I'm using to fade the text of my quotes in and out crashes my browser, code follows.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style type="text/css">h1 { font-size: 60px; 
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
color: #F5F5F5;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
text-align: center;
}
html { 
  background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/9176/gipuztaktb22sw36g.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

subline {
display: run-in;
width:80%;
height:5px;
background-color:#F5F5F5;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
position: relative;
left: 10%;
}

p {
color: #F5F5F5;
font-size: 20px; 
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Caption" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>HD188753</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
<body style="">
  <h1>HD188753
    <subline></subline>
  </h1>
  <p id="Quote" style="display: none; ">
    "Metaphysical  
    <b> quote </b>
    here"
  </p>


<script>
function pausecomp(ms) {
ms += new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms){}
} 

x = 0;
while (x < 1)
{
$("p").fadeOut(400);
pausecomp(2000);
$("p").fadeIn(400);
pausecomp(2000);
}


</script></body>
```

Anyway, thanks for any advice or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loops keep the JavaScript engine running at 100% (because of the infinite loop).  You need to look at the `complete` parameter for `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`, and you need to learn about JavaScript's `setTimeout` method.

Basically, the `complete` function runs after the animation is complete.  The `setTimeout` is self-explanatory: it runs the specified function after the specified amount of time has elapsed.  Here's an example:

```
function fadeOut() {
    $("p").fadeOut(400, function () {
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 2000);
    });
}

function fadeIn() {
    $("p").fadeIn(400, function () {
        setTimeout(fadeOut, 2000);
    });
}

fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 0;
while (x < 1)
{
$("p").fadeOut(400);
pausecomp(2000);
$("p").fadeIn(400);
pausecomp(2000);
}
```

You are in an infinite loop. The value of x is not being manipulated anywhere inside the loop, so that is trying to perform the fadeIn and fadeOut infinite number of times which would kill the browser's window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "crashing", but there's an infinite loop in your code

```
x = 0;
while (x < 1) { ... }
```

Which can be why your code never completes.

Comment: I thought the loop meant it would do the fade in and out inside the loop an infinite time as I wanted, is that wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it's wrong. JavaScript does only one thing at a time, so that code spends all its time fading stuff in and out, allowing nothing else on the page to run.